# Sharing RxBindings Observable events between multiple subscribers

Tags: android, publish-subscribe, rx-java, rx-android

I'm using a Focus Observable from the RxBindings library to react on focus changes. As I want to either validate input and trigger an animation I need the focus events twice. Jake Wharton recommends to use the share() operator for multiple subscriptions on one observable. But if I manipulate the observable after using share() the first subscription is dead.

This is a small example of my usecase

```
public class ShareTest extends AppCompatActivity {

@Bind(R.id.editTextOne)
EditText editTextOne;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_share_test);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    Observable<Boolean> focusChangeObservable = RxView.focusChanges(editTextOne);
    focusChangeObservable.subscribe(focused -> Log.d("test","Subscriber One: "+focused));

    focusChangeObservable.share().skip(1).filter(focused -> focused == false).subscribe(focused -> {
        Log.d("test","Subscriber Two: "+focused);
    });
}
}
```

What I need and expected was an output when I gain and loose the focus on the EditText is

```
Focus gain
Subscriber One: true

Focus loss
Subscriber One: false
Subscriber Two: false
```

But what I actually get is

```
Focus gain

Focus loss
Subscriber Two: false
```

So it seems the manipulation of the second case overrides the first one.
What am I doing wrong and what is the intended way to share events between multiple subscribers when they are manipulated differently

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*RxView.focusChanges()* Observable sets new *OnFocusChangeListener* on View each time you subscribe to it, so the previous listener will not get any new calls.

In your code you have two subscriptions - first directly on *focusChangeObservable* and the second one is *share* operator

Turning your observable into a ConnectableObservable via *share* operator is a good idea, though you need to subscribe to Observable returned by *share* each time f.e :

```
    final Observable<Boolean> sharedFocusChangeObservable = focusChangeObservable.share();
    sharedFocusChangeObservable.subscribe(focused -> Log.d("test","Subscriber One: "+focused));
    sharedFocusChangeObservable.skip(1).filter(focused -> focused == false).subscribe(focused -> {
        Log.d("test","Subscriber Two: "+focused);
    });
```